# Begin Editing on Insert

Tags: cocoa, core-data, binding, tableview, edit

I've got a document based App using Core Data, and have a tableView which is populated using bindings and an NSArrayController in IB.  Everything works fine, but I wanted to make sure that The first column would be in edit mode immediately on adding a new object to the array.
I looked around for suitable code and adapted some from the Hillegass book.  The editing works fine, but the row selection doesn't seem to be working. It stays at row 0 and when tabbing after editing the next column to be edited is on that row.  Here's a version of the code I've used.  I've googled for the solution to my problem but keep getting results either without Core Data or bindings, or a non document application. 
Am I missing something here?

```
-(IBAction)addEmployee:(id)sender {

Employee *newEmployee = (Employee *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

//Fetch the update Employees
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *employeeEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:employeeEntity];

NSArray *fetchResults = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[fetchRequest release];

NSError *error = nil; 

if (fetchResults == nil) {
    // Something here to handle the error.
    NSLog(@"The fetch results is null");
}

int row = [fetchResults indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:newEmployee];


NSLog(@"row is %d",row);

[[tableView window] endEditingFor:nil];

[tableView editColumn:1 row:row withEvent:nil select:YES];
```

}

Here's the fixed (and vastly simpified) version

```
-(IBAction)addEmployee:(id)sender {

Employee *newEmployee = [newEmployeeController newObject];
[newEmployeeController addObject:newEmployee];

[newEmployeeController rearrangeObjects];

NSArray *fetchResults = [newEmployeeController arrangedObjects];

int row = [fetchResults indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:newEmployee];

[[tableView window] endEditingFor:nil];

[tableView editColumn:1 row:row withEvent:nil select:YES];

    [newEmployee release];
```

}

Comment: Got it sorted. Now I look back and seriously wonder what the heck I was thinking...

Comment: Regarding your fixed version: You are releasing newEmployee too early, and then using it in call to `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:`. Use autorelease, or just release it later.

Comment: OK, I released it down at the bottom instead.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do not need to cast the insertion of the object.  `-insertNewObjectForEntityForName: inManagedObjectContext:` returns `id` so the cast is redudant.

You do not need to fetch the objects just to get the array.  You can query the `NSArrayController` for the new object you added, if it is not there, add it (sorry been a while since I used an `NSArrayController` and don't remember if it needs a cycle of the run loop to detect the change).

From there you can ask the `NSArrayController` for the index and go forward.

Comment: Aha, thank you Mr Zarra..! I think I was trying to be far too clever for my own good. Working perfectly now.  Thanks again (like your Core Data book, by the way).